# Value not printing

Tags: java, desktop-application

I need to find out out why the following code segment doesn't print the value in a swing  application and how to resolve it.

```
         String text = txtResults.getText();
         StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(text);
         StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
         while(token.hasMoreElements())
         {
            String value = token.nextElement().toString();
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int index = 0;index < value.length();index += 8) {
            result.append((char) Integer.parseInt(value.substring(index, index + 8), 2));
            s.append(result);
            }
         }
          System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: A debugger would come in handy. Not a human debugger, mind you.

Comment: What is the value of `text`?

Comment: have you tried:
`System.out.println(s.toString());`

Comment: The value of the text is a binary value. e.g. 0010011001100111

Comment: Even that doesnt print.

Comment: I need to print it in a text area.

Comment: What is your expected output from the binary value `0010011001100111`?

Comment: Its basically a 16 bit array through binary addition. Starting from 16 0's

Comment: This basically prints on console but not on GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this line of code

```
     StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(text);
```

tokenizer breaks a string into tokens by a delimiter (default is `" \t\n\r\f"`). And as per your value of text that is binary (0010011001100111) will not be separated into tokens. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,
Actually I have a list of binaries here. It retrieves from a textboxes getText() method.

Comment: What is the separator between them?

Comment: The delimiter is a comma.

Comment: Basically I have not included a comma between them for printing.

Comment: In that case specify your delimiter comma while creating StringTokenizer

Comment: There is still a problem. The value doesnt print.